# Show that two binary quadratic forms are equivalent

Tags: number-theory

> In class we defined binary quadratic forms by $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2$ and their discriminant as $ac-b^2$. I am supposed to show that for a given $n$ and a prime $p$ with $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $m^2 = np-1$ the forms $f(x,y) = px^2+2\frac{m^2}{2}xy^2+ny^2$ and $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ are equivalent.

If I am not mistaken it should suffice to find a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ such that
$f(A(x,y)) = g(x,y)$. But I do not see how to find such a matrix. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write down the matrices of these two forms:
$$G = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
satisfies $g(x,y) = (x,y)*G*(x,y)^T$ for all $x,y$.
Find the matrix $F$ in a similar way (after you fix your typo in $f$) and then find a transform matrix $T$ such that $TFT^T = G$. It might be possible to do it by hand in this case, but for the general case there should be algorithms (e.g. in your textbook) to get such a $F$ onto normal form.